# issue while converting string to char added some number before it

Tags: c#, type-conversion

when i try to convert the string which have value "R" and convert it to Convert.ToChar("R") it returns 82'R' . i just wants to save the char value in DB which have char type with length 1

Comment: Try to convert the string to **char array** first then get the character from the variable

Comment: Sorry If i misunderstood, but when you say you get "82'R'", do you mean you see it while debugging ?  Convert.ToChar returns a single char. So there is a chance what you visibly see if a IDE feature (82 is ascii value for 'R').

Answer (score 0):

String has a default property that accepts an int and returns the char at that position:

```
if(myStr.Length>0){
  char firstInString = myStr[0];
  //db code here
}
```

Though I think you might find that passing a string of any length to a database query command with a parameter* created as char with a length setting of 1 will only put the first char into the table regardless of how long your c# string is

- you *are* using parametrised queries, right? http://bobby-tables.com if you aren't

Answer (score 0):

You may ignore the "82" because is a ascii value for 'R'. When retrieve value it will show 'R' value only.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
char[] myChr = yourString.ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

don't convert it simply use it.

Code:
char myChar = myString[0];